# its possible put more of 1 name controls on a jquery action?

Tags: jquery

My code has this:-

```
if ($("#cobro").val() === '')
```

In #cobro it's possible:

```
if ($("#cobro #cobro2 #cobro3").val() === '')
```

And do things with that results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put as many selectors as you want, but if you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/), it states that `val()` only returns the value from the first match in the set.

You could solve it by simple converting the collection to an array, and use `Array.every`

```
if ( $("#cobro, #cobro2, #cobro3").toArray().every( el => el.value === "") )
```

```js
if ( $("#cobro, #cobro2, #cobro3").toArray().every( el => el.value === "") ) {
 console.log('All cobro empty');
}

if ( $("#test, #test2, #test3").toArray().every( el => el.value === "") ) {
 console.log('All test empty'); // doesn't run, there's a value in the second one
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="cobro">
<input id="cobro2">
<input id="cobro3">

<input id="test">
<input id="test2" value="stop">
<input id="test3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function validatevalue()
{
  $("#cobro #cobro2 #cobro3").each(function( index ) {
     if($(this).val() == "" )
     {
          alert('Please fill the required information.');
          return false;
     }
  });
}
```